# Flutter query firebase firestore database for random documents - issue in logic

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, random, document

I have a recipe collection on firebase firestore. For generating document IDs on firestore I take advantage of using the auto-generating function. So my document collection looks sth like this:

```
VUHZzY0y3fPihgU5EJSh
XaHZzY4y3fPidfU5EJSj
ABCZzY0y3fKkjfU5EJDu
etc.
```

Now I want to pull 3 random documents from the collection and display them to my users.
I generate a random ID like this:

```
String getRandomGeneratedId() {
  
  const int AUTO_ID_LENGTH = 20;
  const String AUTO_ID_ALPHABET = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
  
  const int maxRandom = AUTO_ID_ALPHABET.length;
  final Random randomGen = Random();
  
  String id = '';
  for (int i = 0; i < AUTO_ID_LENGTH; i++) {
    id = id + AUTO_ID_ALPHABET[randomGen.nextInt(maxRandom)];
     print('RandomID is $id');
  }
  return id;
  }
```

With that I query 3 random documents. Basically I am searching an ID greater than or less than the randomly generated Id. But somewhere there seems to be an issue in the logic. Because sometimes I get for example only 2 documents instead of 3. Although I have the "greater than" or "less than" logic implemented. Where is the mistake in my code/logic?

```
  
Future<List> getData() async {
 
  
    List<Recipe> dataList = [];
   
    // Retrieves 3 random data in a loop
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

      // generate a random index based on the list length
      // and use it to retrieve the element
      
      String _randomIndex = getRandomGeneratedId();
       print('RandomIndex is $_randomIndex');


final query = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('recipes')
    .where("id", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: _randomIndex)
    .orderBy("id")
    .limit(1);
QuerySnapshot response = await query.get();
if (response.docs == null || response.docs.length == 0) {
  final anotherQuery = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('recipes')
      .where('id', isLessThan: _randomIndex)
      .orderBy('id')
      .limit(1);
  response = await anotherQuery.get();
}

    dataList.addAll(response.docs.map((d)=> Recipe.fromJson(d.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)));
   
  final datamodel_transaction = RecipeModelData()
      ..calories = dataList[i].calories
      ..carbs = dataList[i].carbs
      ..title = dataList[i].title
      ..id = dataList[i].id
      ..price = dataList[i].price
      ..url = dataList[i].url
  //    ..servings = dataList[i].servings
      ..protein = dataList[i].protein
      ..fat = dataList[i].fat
      ..ingredients = dataList[i].ingredients
      ..instructions = dataList[i].instructions;
      
  final _box = Boxes.getModelItems();
 
  _box.put(dataList[i].id,datamodel_transaction);
  print('Values of data model are ${_box.values}');

     
    }

    return dataList;

  
  }
```

Edit: I think I found the issue. As I don't have a lot of documents in the database, this happens: First random ID pulls document for "garlic pasta", second random ID pulls document for "tomato bread" and the third random ID pulls again "tomato bread". As I save the results in a hive box, the first "tomato bread" entry gets overwritten. As a result the user can only see tomato bread and garlic pasta - no third recipe. So I need to check if the document exists already in the box and if yes, then another document needs to be pulled. Can someone help me with the code?